# javascript get variable into module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I get some variables into a module similar to this

The 1st file (i.e. the main file)is like this

```
require('specific_module');
object.method('specific_module')
```

The 2nd file (i.e. specific_module.js)would get variable passed from the 1st and return the object

```
var objectVar = require('./mother_file')
objectVar.method('specific_module');
```

3rd file (i.e. mother_file)

```
require(library)
exports.createConnection = function (objectName){
    return library(objectName)
}
```

how can I get pass objectName from 1st file to 3rd file. Please not that there is no export in 2nd file and
    2nd file is not a function

I thought that something like this would work but I do not know how to use it

```
require('specific_module').method('variableStr')
```

**Update**

There are some operation which the 2nd file(specific_module) would perform and would pass the
output to another the third file. Like this

```
                    [mother_file]
            perform some operation
                    |
                    |
            -----------------------------------
            |                                   |
        2nd file
        do some other operatn
            |
    --------------------
    |                   |
    1st file            1st file
                some operation
```

I hope that you can get why the structure is like that 3rd file would have to go thru 2nd's operation before
going to the 1st file.

I was hoping that require('specific_module').method('variableStr') would work so that I can pass a variable to 
a file when it is required and let that file make use of that variable before returning the file's object

```
require('specific_module').method('variableStr')
```

Comment: you can `require('mother_file')` on the first file

Comment: There is no way to pass a variable through the 2nd file without an export or a global variable.

Comment: @S Dra what is the 'method' function in 'specific_module.js' defined with?

Comment: @GrafiCode the update shows a design pattern for the work

Comment: @Trobol do you have any idea how something like this works   require('specific_module').method('variableStr')

Comment: Can you show your actual code? Its very hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish.